# glassfish: while deploying the app IOException: invalid zip file

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb, ear

In deploying the EAR through the CLI, this error occurs:

```
Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseLegacy] : java.io.IOException: invalid zip file: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/application /EnterpriseLegacy/lib/RemoteEJB.jar
```

and yet, Netbeans deploys the same EAR fine from within the IDE.

I think the problem is that the EJB module depends on a remote interface, `RemoteEJB` which builds as a JAR.  This JAR is included with the EAR, but I don't believe that's sufficient.  I've tried placing it in `glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext/` and `glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/`, however, that doesn't resolve or change the exception.

Is the problem that the `RemoteEJB` JAR needs to be available on glassfish?  Before this EJB implemented this interface, it deployed fine.  (The reason the EJB implements a remote interface is so that the EJB is available for the web module.)

Deploying from within Netbeans, before and after:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
EnterpriseLegacy  <ear, web, ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$
```

glassfish log of deployment from Netbeans:

```
[2014-10-02T22:04:41.808-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681808] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB MySingletonQueue: [java:global/EnterpriseLegacy/EnterpriseLegacy-ejb/MySingletonQueue!db.RemoteQueue, java:global/EnterpriseLegacy/EnterpriseLegacy-ejb/MySingletonQueue]]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.914-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681914] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.926-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681926] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.929-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681929] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.939-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681939] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.950-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681950] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:41.954-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312681954] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:42.523-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312682523] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/EnterpriseLegacy-war']]

[2014-10-02T22:04:43.199-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312683199] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [EnterpriseLegacy#EnterpriseLegacy-war.war] at [EnterpriseLegacy-war]]]

[2014-10-02T22:04:43.267-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1412312683267] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EnterpriseLegacy was successfully deployed in 2,144 milliseconds.]]
```

and the web module runs as expected when deployed from Netbeans.  How can I deploy the EAR manually to Glassfish?

deploying the EAR from the CLI:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy NetBeansProjects/EnterpriseLegacy/dist/EnterpriseLegacy.ear
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseLegacy] : java.io.IOException: invalid zip file: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/EnterpriseLegacy/lib/RemoteEJB.jar. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
thufir@dur:~$
```

glassfish log of failed manual deploy:

```
[2014-10-02T21:20:47.809-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1412310047809] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseLegacy] : java.io.IOException: invalid zip file: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/EnterpriseLegacy/lib/RemoteEJB.jar
java.io.IOException: invalid zip file: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/EnterpriseLegacy/lib/RemoteEJB.jar
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.createEntryEnumeration(InputJarArchive.java:451)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.entries(InputJarArchive.java:203)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.access$100(InputJarArchive.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$1.enumeration(InputJarArchive.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$CollectionWrappedEnumeration.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:728)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.getDirectories(InputJarArchive.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDetector.isEARFromIntrospecting(EarDetector.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDetector.handles(EarDetector.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isArchiveOfType(DeploymentUtils.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isArchiveOfType(DeploymentUtils.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.resources.util.ResourceUtil.hasResourcesXML(ResourceUtil.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.resources.util.ResourceUtil.hasResourcesXML(ResourceUtil.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.resources.connector.ResourcesCompositeSniffer.handles(ResourcesCompositeSniffer.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.internal.deployment.GenericSniffer.handles(GenericSniffer.java:105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.getSniffers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:658)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

The EJB implements this remote interface:

package db;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteQueue {

```
public int getNext();
```

}

the EJB in the `EnterpriseLegacy-ejb` module:

package db;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MySingletonQueue implements RemoteQueue {

```
int i = 3;

@Override
public int getNext() {
    return i;
}
```

}

the structure of `EnterpriseLegacy` with an EJB and web module:

```
NetBeansProjects/EnterpriseLegacy/
├── build.xml
├── EnterpriseLegacy-ejb
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   ├── setup
│   │   └── glassfish-resources.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── conf
│       │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│       │   └── persistence.xml
│       └── java
│           └── db
│               ├── Clients.java
│               ├── ClientsJpaController.java
│               ├── exceptions
│               │   ├── IllegalOrphanException.java
│               │   ├── NonexistentEntityException.java
│               │   ├── PreexistingEntityException.java
│               │   └── RollbackFailureException.java
│               ├── MySingletonQueue.java
│               └── Queries.java
├── EnterpriseLegacy-war
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   ├── setup
│   │   └── sun-resources.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── dur
│   │           └── MySessionBean.java
│   └── web
│       ├── index.xhtml
│       ├── menu.xhtml
│       ├── next.xhtml
│       ├── template.xhtml
│       └── WEB-INF
│           └── web.xml
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   └── private.xml
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    └── conf
        └── MANIFEST.MF
```

note that when the EAR is unzipped, the interface JAR is included (as it should be):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EnterpriseLegacy/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EnterpriseLegacy/dist$ ll lib/
total 1280
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir    4096 Oct  2 21:35 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 thufir thufir    4096 Oct  2 21:36 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 1302203 Oct  2 21:35 javaee-web-api-7.0.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir       0 Oct  2 21:35 RemoteEJB.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EnterpriseLegacy/dist$
```

Somehow Netbeans is including `RemoteEJB`, which is the interface for the EJB, in the deployment.  How and where is Netbeans deploying the JAR to Glassfish?  If that is, in fact, the source of the error.

Comment: perhaps there's a way to include the JAR in the deploy command from asadmin?  https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/more_with_deploy_libraries

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem right now and it was being caused by a wrong JDBC resource name. Once I fixed this in persistence.xml the .ear deployed successfully.